# Whats wrong in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query works perfectly in SQL Server 2018 and more new versions, but not working in 2008 R2 (v10.5).

When I remove the second `and`, it's working in that old version, but I need the second "and" :)

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) AS "KrediKartı" 
FROM 
    [SAMBA4].[dbo].[Payments] 
WHERE 
    Date BETWEEN '2022-10-29 03:00:00.000' AND '2022-10-30 03:00:00.617' 
    AND PaymentTypeId = 2
```

When I execute this query in the old SQL Server version, I get this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near ' '

Comment: While there are other issues I am not able to reproduce the error message. Is there more to the query than shown?

Comment: copy the query from this site again in your gui, there will be only some characters that the gui don't like

Comment: Your statement `When I remove second "and", working in old version but I need second "and"` does not really make sense. Please show the query that is working and which that is not working and under which version of SQL Server

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** - we have 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 in the works - so pick what you **really** are talking about ..

Comment: AFAIK the second `AND` is needed in all versions of all SQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed. This query work all versions.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) AS "KrediKartı" 
FROM 
    [SAMBA4].[dbo].[Payments] 
WHERE 
(PaymentTypeId=2) 
AND 
(DATE BETWEEN '2022-11-06 03:00:00.000' AND '2022-11-07 03:00:00.617')
```